# Overriding a parent method and making it private/protected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to make the `create` method private/protected for an `ActiveRecord` model. I want to do something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create(options)
    private
    super(options)

  end
end
```

so that I am unable to do `Product.create(...)`. However, I need to do this

```
class Pencil < Product
    def self.create(options)
        options["category"] = "stationary"
        super(options)
    end
end
```

so that I **can** do this `Pencil.create(...)`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question title sounds strange; when I read it I thought you wanted to make a method that's public in the parent private/protected in the child (which doesn't make much sense IMO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def create(options)
      super(options)
    end

    private :create
  end
end

class Pencil < Product
  class << self
    def create(options)
      options["category"] = "stationary"
      super(options)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `class << self` do?